# SQLALCHEMY different between query and execute

Tags: sqlalchemy

Could anyone explain me how rewrite this code to SQLALCHEMY 2.0 syntax (execute)?

```
post = session.query(Post).filter(Post.id == ...). first() 
author = post.author
```

I'm trying to make

```
post = session.execute(select(Post).where(Post.id == ...).first()
author = post.author
```

But this returns me an error that post have not author column!!!

Answer (score 4):

In general, [Session.execute().first()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.first) returns a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)-like [Row](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row) for each row found by the query. This makes the behaviour of SQLAlchemy's core and ORM layers consistent.

`session.execute(select(Post).where(Post.id == ...).first()` returns a *single element row*. To access the value of `Post.author` you could do

```py
result = session.execute(select(Post).where(Post.id == ...)).first()
post = result[0]
author = post.author

# or just
# author = result[0].author
```

However when using the ORM you can use [session.scalars](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.scalars) to get ORM instances directly:

```py
post = session.scalars(select(Post).where(Post.id == ...)).first()
author = post.author
```

Note that in SQLAlchemy 2.0, when using `first` the entire resultset is fetched from the server and then the first result is taken and the rest discarded. Setting a limit may be more efficient:

```py
author = session.execute(select(Post).where(Post.id == ...).limit(1)).first()
```

Answer (score 1):

As @snakecharmerb has already said, `session.execute()` returns a tuple and you should use

```
session.execute(select(Post).where(Post.id == ...).limit(1)).scalars().first()
```

or shorter

```
session.scalars(select(Post).where(Post.id == ...).limit(1)).first()
```

to get an object.

You can also use `session.get()`:

```
post = session.get(Post, POST_ID)
```